# solr terms component not returning results

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I'm trying to do autocomplete using solr's terms component, but I'm not getting any results returned.

my query:

```
/solr/terms?&terms.fl=autocomplete_field&wt=json&omitHeader=true
```

my schema:

```
<field name="autocomplete_field" type="text_tag" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" />

<fieldType name="text_tag" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

my result:

```
{"terms":{"autocomplete_field":{}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the terms Component enabled.
Can you check if `terms` is set to true.

```
 <searchComponent name="termsComponent" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

 <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <bool name="terms">true</bool>
   </lst>
   <arr name="components">
     <str>termsComponent</str>
   </arr>
 </requestHandler>
```

You can also pass `terms=true` as a request parameter and check.